# Phonegap app and LocalStorage

Tags: html, cordova

I'm wondering how safe it would be to use html5 LocalStorage in a Phonegap app to store a user session.

Ideally I would store the user id + a random string to verify his identity on the database, much like a typical 'remember me' cookie.

Is this a safe practice? Anything I might be overlooking when it comes to storing data on Phonegap apps? Maybe something outside of LocalStorage?

Answer (score 1):

Data saved in localStorage is not encrypted so any app/process that has access to that memory could read the value, similar to storing sensitive data in a cookie.

Recommend that instead of saving the userId in localStorage, save a non-identifiable session key.  Or hash the userId and save that value instead (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).